# Search value from one dataframe into another dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have one *dataframe* which has *psno*

`psno - 20140200, 20137760`

then search these value into another df

[image: <code>psno in 2 df</code>]

I want to do take each psno from 1df and searches it with each psno of 2df

and after that it finds the *psno* in 2df I want to apply *ifelse*?

Comment: Try `df2$newColumn <- ifelse(df2$psno %in% df1$psno, "yes", "no")`

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, and expected output.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to filter your data first you could try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% filter(psno_var %in% psno) %>% ...
```

or if you need each psno individually, you could use a for loop:

```
for(i in psno){
   df1 %>% filter(psno_var == i) %>% ...
}
```

or if you're not into the dplyr solutions you can index with `which`

```
df1[which(df1$psno_var %in% psno),]
```

Then you could use your `ifelse` statements.